# Java KeyListener.keyPressed firies multiple times while key is held down

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent, keycode

When using keyListeners,how do you make it so that the value of count only increases by one each time the user presses the left key instead of increase based on how long you hold it?

```
public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
          keyLabel.setText("left");
          count++;}
```

Comment: Create a boolean in the field of that class. When `keyPressed` gets called, you should check the value of this boolean. If it's already `true`, do nothing. If it's `false`, set it to `true` then increment. In `keyReleaseded`, set the boolean to `false`

Comment: i added the code but what if I press the left button twice, can I make it increase 1 each time i press it?

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example of a `KeyListener` that would count each press of `VK_LEFT` only once - even if key is held down and firing multiple times.

```
label.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

       boolean pressed = false;
       @Override
       public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e){
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT && !pressed){
                pressed = true;
                keyLabel.setText("left");
                System.out.println("Pressed: " + (++count));
            }
       }
       @Override
       public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e){
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
                pressed = false;
                System.out.println("Released.");
            }
       }                
   });
```

While keyPressed seems to be repeatedly called while key is pressed, keyReleased is only fired once the key is released, so we toggle a boolean switch `pressed` at that time.